# Linux Libertine O and Linux Biolinum O not found

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, warnings, libertine

I have TeX Live 2011. I set

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
```

but I get a warning that these fonts are not found! If I try `\usepackage{libertineotf}`, I get the same warning. I compile with `xelatex`. Please tell me what is wrong.

Comment: Imho in texlive xetex doesn't search the texmf trees for open type fonts. You will either have to add them to fontconfig or install the fonts in your system.

Comment: Maybe this is not the problem here, but sometimes the "O" is not part of the font name. Run `fc-list :outline -f "%{family}\n"` in a terminal to get a list of available fonts and check the name.

Comment: Please, add the information about your operating system.

Comment: @egreg. My OS is the last of MacBookPro. Probably the Libertine font is already in TeXLive 2011 distribution.

Comment: Once you get the font path issue settled, please consider using the `libertinus` fonts instead. Libertinus Serif is an updated fork of Linus Libertine O, and Libertinus Mono is an updated for of Linux Biolinum O. There is also Libertinus Mono (Linux Libertine Mono O) and Libertinus Math. The one package `libertinus` has them all. No *.sty file or *.fd files, because the Libertinus fonts are ONLY Open Type, so they ONLY work with `fontspec`.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following code to help with supporting xetex and pdftex with Linux Libertine and Latin Modern Mono along with Biolinum. You need to use fontspec, and you don't need to load the libertine package at all with xetex unless you want some of the libertine-specific glyph commands, so you can remove it.

```
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\ifxetex
    \usepackage{libertine}
    \usepackage[log-declarations=false]{xparse} % same as below
  \usepackage[quiet]{fontspec} % remove quiet option to check for errors
  \setromanfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{Linux  Libertine O}
  \setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{Linux  Libertine O}
    \setmonofont[SmallCapsFont={Latin Modern Mono Caps}]{Latin Modern Mono Light}
    \setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
    \usepackage{xunicode}
\else
    \usepackage{sansmath}
    %\usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{libertine}
    \usepackage{DejaVuSansMono}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp}
  \usepackage{epstopdf}
  \usepackage[final,expansion=true,protrusion=true,spacing=true,kerning=true]{microtype}
\fi
```

TeX Live should have the fonts installed already, but I use miktex, so I can't help with distribution specific troubles. Remember to rehash your db.

Update: disregard DejaVuSansMono and update the pdftex code accordingly.