# How to install a font on MacTeX 2013

Tags: fonts, installing

I don't understand why fonts that work perfectly fine on Windows with TeXLive 2013 don't work on my Mac with MacTeX-2013, but whatever. I need to install "Linux Libertine O," but do not know how to do it. The instructions I find online all seem to be for older versions of MacTeX and OS X. I need the font to work with XeLaTeX. If there is a large font distribution/package of some sort that I can use that would be ideal so that I don't keep having to install fonts one by one.

Comment: May be Related [Linux Libertine package and fonts not working anymore (fall 2012)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78516/15717) and [Linux Libertine O and Linux Biolinum O not found](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51803/15717) and Linked Q's

Comment: @texenthusiast I found that but the directions were not helpful for me.

Comment: I don't have the libertine package, and I don't know how to install packages - so I'm dead in the water for that also. I figured I'd start by trying to just install a simple font before learning that stuff.

Comment: @texenthusiast `fontspec error: The font "Linux Libertine O" cannot be found.`

Comment: It works fine on my Windows installation of TeXLive 2013

Comment: @texenthusiast can you [chat?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends)

Comment: Do you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX? If you use the former, you should use the actual names of the font files rather than "logical" names such as "Linux Libertine O".

Comment: @Mico concrete example please, I don't know what the 'actual name' is.

Comment: @Mico it works fine on Windows using XeLaTeX. It just won't work on the Mac.

Comment: @Dan: A reason why your document compiles under Windows but not under MacOSX is that the fonts *may* be activated on your Windows machine but not (yet) on your Mac. If that's the case, you'll need to use the method described in Joseph Wright's answer, viz., use each font's exact file name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have Linux Libertine installed as an OTF in your Mac? If so, using `fontspec` + XeLaTeX should "just work".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
Testing, 1, 2, 3.
\end{document}
```

> $ pdffonts ~/tmp/TeX/libertine.pdf
>
> name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
>
> ---
>
> OKMUQH+LinLibertineO-Identity-H      CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      5  0

[image]

edit: As per Joseph Wright's request for clarification: I have installed the Linux Libertine OTF package as a system-wide font (i.e. accessible to any application on my Mac)

Comment: I installed all packages in MacTeX. Joseph's answer works for me, but not this one. So I have the package. I think the procedure of picking the filename of Libertine is exact way to go. Most probably least problems between different OSX systems. It would be interesting to see how you installed the system-wide font to compare better to Joseph's answer.

Comment: I just installed the libertine fonts through fontbook (double clicked them from the finder, and installed them). I just tried the MWE again (I'm running Yosemite in a new machine) and it just works. No idea why it's not working for you. Did you install libertine as a system-wide font? If not, that's the problem.

Comment: No libertine in my Fontbook. How did you install libertine as a system-wide font? - I do no get it why I should do it, since the font exists in my system and not necessarily to install anything extra. Using Joseph's answer works like a charm!

Comment: You can just open a finder window on the folder that Joseph pointed to, select the otf files and open them in fontbook. You'll get the option to install them. Once installed, you can use them in all Mac apps, not only LaTeX (which is why I install all my fonts system wide).
Also, using this method allows you to use _any_ system font, not only the ones that come with TeXlive, and you don't need to know about the OTF file names.

Answer (score 7):

XeTeX uses system-dependent code to load fonts, hence it's quite possible to see differences between how Windows and Mac installations find fonts. What will always work is looking not for the 'friendly' name of the font but the font file name:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle]{LinLibertine_R.otf}
\begin{document}
Testing, 1, 2, 3.
\end{document}
```

I'm using the files inside `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine`, *i.e.*  without a 'stand alone' installation of Linux Libertine for use by non-TeX programs. Again, this can be important! (See also [mvarela's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127266))

Comment: This is the best answer here! Works in the newest OSX installation well. Seems to be also much more robust and stable way of picking the font, since the file should always be the same. I think this way should of use should be mentioned widely for OSX users. Old way of sticking to Hoefler's font here and ignoring the Libertine http://www.latextemplates.com/template/compact-academic-cv