# Change all Linux Libertine font

Tags: libertine

I want to buld a book, but I have non stop error! The file use everywhere on tex file Linux Libertine O and other linux libertine font.
I would like to know, how to change all font without change every font by another font.

```
\documentclass[12pt,french]{book}
\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Biolinum O}

\begin{document}
\include{frontmatter}
\pagestyle{headings}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{touslesserpents}
\include{8multipliés}
\include{Tortues}
ABC abc
\end{document}
```

Error is :

```
The font "Linux Libertine O" cannot be found.
The font "Linux Biolinum O" cannot be found
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Could you explain what you want to do, as well? What do you mean by changing all the fonts (?) without changing every font? We definitely need an MWE to see how you are configuring the fonts now. It would also help to know *what* errors you are getting - what makes you think the font is the problem?

Comment: What happens if you replace `\usepackage{libertine}` with `\usepackage{fontspec}`?

Comment: even after your edit, the question is totally unclear. You have specified linux libertine, but you haven't said which font you want to change or which font you want to use instead.

Comment: You need to install the linux libertine fonts or delete the lines `\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Biolinum O}
`  and use the default tex fonts instead

Comment: If I delete `\usepackage{libertine} \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O} \setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O} \setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Biolinum O}` I always error because the othor because the author has add `\fontspec{Linux Libertine O C}` or other font throughout on tex file. (Linux libertine font is instaled on my mac)

Comment: Yes i compile with xelatex. This is the file [link](https://code.google.com/p/swfk-fr/source/checkout)

Comment: @SigmaPi: Well, your example runs without problems, but your are not showing the relevant portion, I fear. I believe, `\fontspec{Linux Libertine O C}` is wrong in this case, but removing the `C` in that will provide a working MWE

Comment: Yes, if you are the editor and the author is using broken commands, then either consider getting the author to make changes throughout, or just use a `sed` command to rewrite the incorrect strings.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The fonts are included in standard TeX distributions in opentype format, as well as type1.

Comment: @cfr they are, but then tex wouldn't say it couldn't find them in a standard distribution, so given the rather sketchy information in the question, backing stuff out to get a working document seems like the start of a plan:-)

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is probably just to load the `libertine` package. This package will automatically detect that you are using XeLaTeX or LuaTeX and load `fontspec` in that case. If you are using LaTeX or pdfLaTeX, it will use a traditional font configuration instead.

```
\documentclass[12pt,french]{book}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
\include{frontmatter}
\pagestyle{headings}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{touslesserpents}
\include{8multipliés}
\include{Tortues}
\end{document}
```

I do get a couple of warnings in this case. Apparently, the `libertine` package attempts to pick some font features which the fonts don't actually support. (At least, not in the versions I have.) But starting with the package is definitely the best strategy. You can then customise it by picking appropriate options if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what operating system or TeX platform you're using but on Ubuntu with TeXLive 2014 this works for me, when compiled with `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,french]{book}
\usepackage[MnSymbol]{mathspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Biolinum O}

\begin{document}
« Bonjour tout le monde ! »
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, if that does not work, try:

```
\documentclass[12pt,french]{book}
\usepackage[MnSymbol]{mathspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Biolinum}

\begin{document}
« Bonjour tout le monde ! »
\end{document}
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem?

Comment: On OS X 10.10 and all tex update installed this code doesn't work! `fontspec error: "font-not-found" The font "Linux Libertine O" cannot be found.`

Comment: Try `Linux Libertine` and `Linux Biolinum` without the `O` at the end and see if that works.

Comment: Same probleme...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it is a Minimum Working Example which is generally the first step towards solving a LaTeX problem.

Comment: @JoeCorneli: Yes, it's a starter, but still not the solution ;-) I tested the OP's MWE half an hour ago and it run without problems ;-) I suspect the error in those `\fontspec{...}` commands, see my comment below the OP

Comment: Googling the error message ponts to this prior question, have a look: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51803/linux-libertine-o-and-linux-biolinum-o-not-found

Comment: @ChristianHupfer now that the OP has tested this MWE and found that it fails, attention is focused on getting _this_ MWE to work.

Comment: The key part may be this remark on the linked question "Remember to rehash your db."  `sudo mktexlsr` or whatever the equivalent is on your machine.

Comment: @JoeCorneli I already find the discution but I have other error. What is db?

Comment: Ok I fund a part of the solution! If I remove the O that work. thx @JoeCorneli